# Odoo12: Receiving CSRF validation failed on path '/website_form/crm.lead' on form submission

Tags: forms, odoo-12

I'm receiving the below error from an attempt to use a webform to make a Lead.  When making the form Odoo 12 also won't let me access any of the existing fields in the Lead model. The following error (from the logs) is all the information that I have along with the form error on the website. This issue is only for the CRM and Tasks all other forms submit just fine.

I'm trying to build a form to submit a Lead.

Instead of the form submitting I recieve the following error in the logs.

> 2019-08-07 10:37:50,152 28624 WARNING tdb_test_2019-08-07_c1
>   odoo.http: CSRF validation failed on path '/website_form/crm.lead'

Comment: Sounds like you have invalid csrf posted with your form data. It is hard to comment more without seeing exact code and setup. Please share relevant code in your question.

Comment: I didn't actually write any code for this form.  I built it using the Form builder.  The only thing that I changed was renaming the fields as it wouldn't let me select any existing fields from the model.